# Find the maximum and minimum of $\sum \limits_{i=1}^n x_i ^3$ given three constraints

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, maxima-minima, integer-programming, sums-of-squares

> Let $x_1,x_2, \dots ,x_n$ be a sequence of integers such that
>
> $i)\quad\ \  -1\le x_i\le 2$ for $i=1,2,\dots,n$
>
> $ii)\quad \ \,x_1+x_2+\dots+x_n=19$
>
> $iii)\quad{x_1}^2+{x_2}^2+\dots +{x_n}^2=99$
>
> Determine the minimum and maximum values of $\sum \limits_{i=1}^n  x_i^3$

I tried using the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, and some others, but it appears something difficult. I think I am missing something.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A simple approach would be to simply count the numbers of $x_i$ taking the values $-1$, $1$ and $2$. Denote these numbers by $a$, $b$ and $c$, respectively. Then we have
\begin{eqnarray*}
\sum_{i=1}^nx_i   &=&-1\times a+1\times b+2\times c &=& 19,\\
\sum_{i=1}^nx_i^2 &=&\ \quad1\times a+1\times b+4\times c &=& 99.
\end{eqnarray*}
This shows that $a+c=40$, so $c=40-a$ and $b=3a-61$. Then
\begin{eqnarray*}
\sum_{i=1}^nx_i^3&=&-1\times a+1\times b+8\times c=-a+(3a-61)+8(40-a)=259-6a,\\
\end{eqnarray*}
where of course $21\leq a\leq40$ because $b,c\geq0$, which shows that we have sharp bounds
$$19\leq\sum_{i=1}^nx_i^3\leq133.$$